# Authentication servers are down

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

im hosting a server and this error will always display, only on my server! Im hosting on Ubuntu server OS, so how can I fix this error for my server?

This is home-hosted

Comment: Is it hosted on your own server (at your home etc) or on a VM on Cloud etc.?

Comment: your server may not be connected to the internet.

Comment: Check your firewall settings.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the servers which authenticate Minecraft users when they log onto your server cannot be reached. This could be for two reasons:

1. Your server cannot reach the internet

This opens up a rabbit hole of networking issues which I'm not very knowledgeable about, and would need more information to help anyway. Hopefully someone else can suggest something.

2. The servers are actually down

While rare, I have seen this happen before in which case it passed in a few hours. In the meantime you can set the `online-mode=` option in your `server.properties` file to `false`. Please note that this represents a minor security risk as hackers can connect to your server with fabricated usernames. This also should allow players on your LAN to connect if you're not connected to the internet correctly, but if you're having internet troubles then you will likely find your server to be very lonely...

Comment: Minor security risk? I would say really big major one. If use of online=false, then ONLY in first scenario, where server is offline to internet, and never if server is accessible to internet....... Mojang servers are not down often, I would rather say that server's IP could've been blocked temporary for too many requests than Mojang is down.